# How to check multiple HTML5 videos for audio

Tags: javascript, html, audio, video

I'm trying to check to see if multiple videos have audio or not, like this:
**https://jsfiddle.net/hrd4a0c3/**

but this only checks one video, I want this to check multiple videos.

```
document.getElementById("myVideo").addEventListener("loadeddata", function() {
  if (typeof this.webkitAudioDecodedByteCount || this.mozHasAudio || this.audioTracks !== "undefined") {
    if (this.webkitAudioDecodedByteCount > 0 || this.mozHasAudio || this.audioTracks && this.audioTracks.length)
      this.after("has audio");
    else
      this.after("no audio");
  }
});
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would use `class` instead of `id`, since ids are supposed to refer to one element.

```
<video class='myVideo' autoplay loop muted>
  <source src="https://vtt.tumblr.com/tumblr_ok41s7Iebh1t4fjz0_480.mp4" type="video/mp4">
</video>

<video class='myVideo' autoplay loop muted>
  <source src="https://vtt.tumblr.com/tumblr_ok44bpZZka1t4fjz0_480.mp4" type="video/mp4">
</video>
```

Then you can use [`getElementsByClassName`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/API/Document/getElementsByClassName) like so:

```
var videos = document.getElementsByClassName("myVideo");

for (i = 0; i < videos.length; i++) {
  videos[i].addEventListener("loadeddata", function() {
    if (typeof this.webkitAudioDecodedByteCount || this.mozHasAudio || this.audioTracks !== "undefined") {
      if (this.webkitAudioDecodedByteCount > 0 || this.mozHasAudio || this.audioTracks && this.audioTracks.length)
        this.after("has audio");
      else
        this.after("no audio");
    }
  });
}
```

**Updated [Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/hrd4a0c3/3/)**

Comment: No problem :) I'm glad it helped.

Comment: Please help me once again, i cant add some html or css in this ".after" dont work

Comment: To insert an html string as content like `("<p>no audio</p>")`, you could use JQuery - [Fiddle Demo](https://jsfiddle.net/hrd4a0c3/5/) - Note in the [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/hrd4a0c3/5/) how JQuery has been added to the external resources on the left bar.

Comment: yea, just $(this), sorry, my bad. I don't have a brain